# Sphinx generates internal members of @dataclass

Tags: python, python-sphinx, inner-classes, python-decorators, python-dataclasses

I have a python internal class that looks like this:

```
class TopClass:
  @my_decorator
  class InternalClass:
    """Persistent state."""
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
```

in this case `my_decorator` is a thin wrapper around @dataclass. Running sphinx however writes in the docs things like:

```
__dataclass_params__= _DataclassParams(init=True,repr=True,eq=True,order=False,unsafe_hash=False, frozen=False)
__dict__= mappingproxy({'__module__': 'my_module.try', '__annotations__': {'a': 'int', 'b': 'int', 'c': 'int'}, '__doc__': 'Persistent state.', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'InternalClass' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'State' objects>, '__dataclass_params__': _DataclassParams(init=True,repr=True,eq=True,order=False,unsafe_hash=False,frozen=False), '__dataclass_fields__': {'a': Field(name='a',type='int',default=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object>,default_factory=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),_field_type=_FIELD), 'b': Field(name='b',type='int',default=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object>,default_factory=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),_field_type=_FIELD), 'c': Field(name='c',type='int',default=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object>,default_factory=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object>,init=True,repr=True,hash=None,compare=True,metadata=mappingproxy({}),_field_type=_FIELD)}, '__init__': <function __create_fn__.<locals>.__init__>, '__repr__': <function __create_fn__.<locals>.__repr__>, '__eq__': <function __create_fn__.<locals>.__eq__>, '__hash__': None})
__eq__(other)
Return self==value.

__hash__= None
__init__(a, b, c)
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: I think you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: It appears that this is not a bug: https://groups.google.com/g/sphinx-users/c/9g2ofJ8W_bg